# "Start: applet not initialized" error Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, applet

When I run my code I get a little applet window that says "Start: applet not initialized" in the bottom left hand corner. I have not actually installed the JRE but got the offline installer and specified where it was in "eclipse.ini", could that be a problem? Below is my code and the errors I get in both the applet and the console.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class SpMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JButton define, conjugate, close;

    SpMain(String title){

        super(title);

        this.setSize(375, 190);
        this.init();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {

        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        JLabel lchoose = new JLabel("Define or Conjugate?");

        define = new JButton("Define");
        conjugate = new JButton("Conjugate");
        close = new JButton("Close");

        define.addActionListener(this);
        conjugate.addActionListener(this);
        close.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(lchoose);
        panel.add(define);
        panel.add(conjugate);
        panel.add(close);

        this.add(panel);
    }

    public void setDefaultCloseOperation(int exitOnClose) {}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if(event.getSource() == define){
        }

        else if(event.getSource() == conjugate){
        }

        else if(event.getSource() == close){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

[Applet and Console Errors Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXmja.png)

Comment: A) You are only showing source for a **JFrame**. I don't see your applet code here. So something is missing from your input ... we cant help without that. B) Applets are somehow dead technology. Are you sure you want to spend your time on them?

Comment: @GhostCat A) The stack trace shown on far right of the screenshot confirms your point. It won't run as an applet, if it's not a `java.awt.Applet` or a `javax.swing.JApplet`. Please upgrade the comment to an answer. B) OP: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). C) OP: Applets are dead (see (B)) that desktop app. can be launched from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).